# Cairo C program won't draw to x11 window

Tags: c, linux, x11, cairo

I'm trying to use the [Cairo](http://cairographics.org/) graphics library on Linux in C to make a pretty lightweight x11 GUI.

After trying very hard to follow the [woefully incomplete guide](http://cairographics.org/Xlib/) that cairo gives for x11, this is the best I've got:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <cairo.h>
#include <cairo-xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/extensions/Xrender.h>
#include <X11/extensions/renderproto.h>

//This function should give us a new x11 surface to draw on.
cairo_surface_t* create_x11_surface(int x, int y)
{
    Display* d;
    Drawable da;
    int screen;
    cairo_surface_t* sfc;

    if((d = XOpenDisplay(NULL)) == NULL)
    {
        printf("failed to open display\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    screen = DefaultScreen(d);
    da = XCreateSimpleWindow(d, DefaultRootWindow(d), 0, 0, x, y, 0, 0, 0);
    XSelectInput(d, da, ButtonPressMask | KeyPressMask);
    XMapWindow(d, da);

    sfc = cairo_xlib_surface_create(d, da, DefaultVisual(d, screen), x, y);
    cairo_xlib_surface_set_size(sfc, x, y);

    return sfc;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //create a new cairo surface in an x11 window as well as a cairo_t* to draw
    //on the x11 window with.
    cairo_surface_t* surface = create_x11_surface(300, 200);
    cairo_t* cr = cairo_create(surface);

    while(1)
    {
        //save the empty drawing for the next time through the loop.
        cairo_push_group(cr);

        //draw some text
        cairo_select_font_face(cr, "serif", CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_NORMAL, CAIRO_FONT_WEIGHT_BOLD);
        cairo_set_font_size(cr, 32.0);
        cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 1.0);
        cairo_move_to(cr, 10.0, 25.0);

        if((argc == 2) && (strnlen(argv[1], 100) < 50))
            cairo_show_text(cr, argv[1]);
        else
            cairo_show_text(cr, "usage: ./p1 <string>");

        //put the drawn text onto the screen(?)
        cairo_pop_group_to_source(cr);
        cairo_paint(cr);
        cairo_surface_flush(surface);

        //pause for a little bit.
        int c = getchar();

        //change the text around so we can see the screen update.
        for(int i = 0; i < strnlen(argv[1], 100); i++)
        {
            argv[1][i] = argv[1][i + 1];
        }

        if(c == 'q')
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    cairo_surface_destroy(surface);
    return 0;
}
```

On Linux systems that have Cairo installed, it can be compiled with

```
gcc -o myprog $(pkg-config --cflags --libs cairo x11) -std=gnu99 main.c
```

And it should be run with a single argument.

For reasons I don't understand at all, inserting the line

```
cairo_pop_group_to_source(cr);
cairo_paint(cr);
cairo_surface_write_to_png (surface, "hello.png");    //<--------- inserted
cairo_surface_flush(surface);
```

Puts something on the screen, but there are 2 problems:

1. Text that I draw with this method is persistent, creating a smearing effect.
2. I don't want some .png file mediating between my program and an x11 window.  Data should be sent directly!

Comment: Your problem is in your choice of backend for cairo. You can choose png, pdf, svg, or you can write directly to a gtk window (which it appears you want to do). See the examples in [**Cairo Tutorial - zetcode**](http://zetcode.com/gfx/cairo/cairobackends/) for examples of each.

Comment: Sorry for my incompetence here; I'm usually an embedded systems developer, I rarely write Linux code.  What's the difference between gtk and x11?  gtk sounds more complex from what I've read.  Can't I write "directly to an x11 window: instead of "directly to a gtk window"?

Comment: No worries, just slow down a little bit and work through the tutorials and you will slowly begin to digest the different capabilities. No matter what you are trying to learn in C, remember it is not a race, and the details that you fly by when in a hurry -- really are important. So enjoy the ride. (not race).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I don't know, in principle you can draw to a `GdkPixmap` which is a drawable just like a `GdkWindow` is, and then use the `GdkPixmap` as a `X11` pixmap to draw to a `X11` window. And when I've compiled *cairo* from source I recall it has a *x11* backend but I am not sure.

Comment: That is a good point, I didn't climb down to the bottom of the cairo API and compare all the various backends. There may be some limitation on a direct write to X11, but the pixmap or window provided the direct write to screen and there are a number of direct X11 conversions at the bottom of that rabbit-hole to check.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I wish I had time to slow down... I'm on a time critical mission to make a debug utility for Verilog.  My hardware project is at a near-standstill until I get this figured out.

Comment: @johnny_boy If you're in a hurry, why are you not targetting something higher-level and more complete? Like, of course, GTK+?

Comment: @unwind  Thanks for the suggestion.  Will a Gnome program run on a system that uses Cinnamon for its window manager though?

Comment: @johnny_boy What? You don't need to do a *GNOME* application, you can use GTK+ without GNOME. From my understanding, that is exactly what Cinnamon is in itself.

Comment: @unwind Thanks a lot for the suggestion.  Gtk is definitely what I want.  I have no idea how I ended up trying to use cairo.

Comment: there is a significant logic error in the code.   After checking argc and finding that no command line parameter was passed, then displaying an error message,  the code continues execution, as if a parameter had been passed.  What the code should have done is cleanup and exit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several issues:

- In X11, the X11 server doesn't save what you drew to a window, but instead sends an `ExposeEvent` to your window that tells it to redraw. This means you get a black window, because you do not handle this event.
- `getchar` only gives you something after a line break, so just typing something won't help.
- libX11 buffers stuff and only sends it to the X11 server when you wait for an event (or the buffer fills up). Since you never wait for an event, it never flushes. Calling `XFlush` explicitly helps.
- The group that you push is useless. Just get rid of it.
- Your code to move the string one direction to the left easily goes beyond the end of the string. You apparently know this already, because you 'fixed' this with a `strnlen`.

Here is a little better solution, but it still gives you an initially black window, because you draw to it before it is mapped:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cairo-xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

//This function should give us a new x11 surface to draw on.
cairo_surface_t* create_x11_surface(Display *d, int x, int y)
{
    Drawable da;
    int screen;
    cairo_surface_t* sfc;

    screen = DefaultScreen(d);
    da = XCreateSimpleWindow(d, DefaultRootWindow(d), 0, 0, x, y, 0, 0, 0);
    XSelectInput(d, da, ButtonPressMask | KeyPressMask);
    XMapWindow(d, da);

    sfc = cairo_xlib_surface_create(d, da, DefaultVisual(d, screen), x, y);

    return sfc;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Display *d = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    if (d == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open display\n");
        return 1;
    }
    //create a new cairo surface in an x11 window as well as a cairo_t* to draw
    //on the x11 window with.
    cairo_surface_t* surface = create_x11_surface(d, 300, 200);
    cairo_t* cr = cairo_create(surface);
    char *text = argv[1];
    size_t text_len = 0;

    if (argc != 2)
        text = NULL;
    else
        text_len = strlen(text);

    while(1)
    {
        // Clear the background
        cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 0);
        cairo_paint(cr);

        //draw some text
        cairo_select_font_face(cr, "serif", CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_NORMAL, CAIRO_FONT_WEIGHT_BOLD);
        cairo_set_font_size(cr, 32.0);
        cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 1.0);
        cairo_move_to(cr, 10.0, 25.0);

        if (text)
            cairo_show_text(cr, text);
        else
            cairo_show_text(cr, "usage: ./p1 <string>");

        cairo_surface_flush(surface);
        XFlush(d);

        //pause for a little bit.
        int c = getchar();

        //change the text around so we can see the screen update.
        memmove(text, &text[1], text_len);
        if (text_len > 0)
            text_len--;

        printf("got char %c\n", c);
        if(c == 'q')
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    // XXX: Lots of other stuff isn't properly destroyed here
    cairo_surface_destroy(surface);
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: Also, why exactly do you feel like cairo only gives you a woefully incomplete guide? It tells you how to get the cairo parts working and it also explains you some parts about X11, even though you should already know those if you want to use cairo-x11. That's none of its business. The guide you linked to even provides a complete, *working* and self-contained example: https://www.cypherpunk.at/files/2014/11/cairo_xlib_simple.c

Comment: "why exactly do you feel like cairo only gives you a woefully incomplete guide?"  Maybe I was being a little harsh, but all of the links to cypherpunk.at are dead, so I wasn't able to view the example code (which would have been very helpful)

Comment: The links to cypherpunk.at are not dead, but its server uses a self-signed certificate (or something else that is not known) so Firefox warns you before continuing; Chrome is even more picky so it may appear to be broken, but it's only a security issue.

Comment: They're dead now. :-(

Answer (score 2):

I've you would have read the complete text of this "imcomplete guide" you would have seen that there is a link to the full sample: https://www.cypherpunk.at/files/2014/11/cairo_xlib_simple.c .